# how to call a modalpopupextender from any page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How do you call a modalpopupextender(dialog panel) from any web page in the application with asp.net. lets say i have an email button on several pages and want to call the emailpopupextender. how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having a similar issue here is a good tutorial for the user_control method of ModelPopupExtender [How To: ModalPopupExtender as UserControl](http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/asp-net-3-5-ajax-modal-popup-extender-with-user-control-event-bubbling/)

Note: From what I've experienced, trying to call MPE in MasterPage from a page in an IFrame doesn't work. If someone has an idea of how to do please post comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your popup extender and all supporting stuff within your MasterPage you could then call it from any page that was rendered as the items would already be there.

If you don't want to do a Master Page solution you could create a UserControl for the process and include that on all pages.

Comment: Yes I am using a Master Page. So I can put the extender in there. Then how would I call it from the page? I actually am displaying certain pages in an IFrame within a content page (for very specific reasons).

Comment: I created the user control with panel, buttons, etc.., put in the page then created modelpopupupextender in code behind on a button click. mpe.show wouldn't show it though. there was no errors either.